# How to get data out of FileReader

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I need a little help with FileReader API. Is there any way how to get data from FileReader outside it. I have a "class" with method, where image is read with FileReader and I want to put image data to the class local variable (as shown in following code).

I do know that FileReader works asynchronously and my solution is wrong. Is there any way how to make it work? Thank you.

```
CanvasState.prototype.addImage = function(inputFile) {
    var file = inputFile;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = this.loadImageData;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

CanvasState.prototype.loadImageData = function(e) {
    this.hasImage = true;
    this.imageData = e.target.result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CanvasState.prototype.addImage = function(inputFile) {
    var file = inputFile, self = this;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
           self.hasImage = true;
            self.imageData = e.target.result;
       };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the way `this` is set in a function. When you do:

```
    foo.bar();
```

`this` inside `bar()` will be `foo`. But if you do:

```
    var bar = foo.bar;
    bar();
```

`this` will be the global object.

In your case, the problem is that when you set `reader.onload`, you are setting it to the function pulled out of the CanvasState prototype. When the reader loads and then calls that function, it is like the example above where the `this` will be the global object, and not  the same it was inside `addImage`.

To fix this, you can use the `bind()` method to create a new function will call `loadImageData` with the `this` you expect.

Basically, change:

```
...
reader.onload = this.loadImageData;
...
```

to:

```
...
reader.onload = this.loadImageData.bind(this);
...
```

Check out [JavaScript Function bind](http://www.javascripture.com/Function#bind) for more info and interactive examples.